# How to construct a non-custom error by Hand in Sails.js

Tags: javascript, error-handling, sails.js

I am writing a Service to be used by my Controllers in my Sails.js application.

If an error is thrown in the Service, I would like to return a error. I am used to the syntax of `function callback(err, bar){ if (err) return error}`. I am in a slightly different case, though. In the following code

```
function callBack(err, uploadedFiles){
    if (err) return err;
    if (uploadedFiles.length == {
       return foo; //This is what needs to be of type "err"
    } 
});
}
}
```

So do I create a JSON object like

```
return { error: "error", message: 404}
```

I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you not using sails functions for responses? I am also new so excuse me if said something silly.

If you want to send a 404 status code which is for Not Found errors the you can use sails provided response res.notFound() like this:

```
return res.notFound({
    message: "Some Message Here"
});
```

If you want to show completely custom message without any status code like 404 then use send() instead like this:

```
return res.send({
    status: "404 or anything you like",
    message: "Some Message Here"
});
```

Sorry, res.send() will also generate a status code but it will be 200 which means OK, so its a success code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is:

```
{success:false, error: err}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can raise your 404 error in your Services like this (assuming your service needs to work asynchronously):

```
var err = new Error('your message');
err.status = 404; // could be other HTTP status
return cb(err);
```

And in your calling function, you can handle the error like this:

```
SomeServices.somefunction(options, function (err, data) {
  // res.negotiate(err) will automatically trigger res.notFound if err.status is 404
  if (err) return res.negotiate(err); 
  /* your logic if not 404 */
}
```

The codes are quite simple here.  Is that what you want?